# Model from Gem is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, mailboxer

I am using [mailboxer](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer) in my Rails 4 app.

```
gem 'mailboxer'
```

I recently updated it from `0.11` to `0.12.4`, it stopped working, and I cant figure out why. Now, I am getting the error:

```
uninitialized constant Message
```

I checked the gem's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/tree/master/app/models/mailboxer) and it does have the `Message` model.

I checked my local version of the gem and it matches up.

> ```
> Puma:mailboxer Jeff$ pwd
> /Users/Jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mailboxer-0.12.4/app/models/mailboxer
> Puma:mailboxer Jeff$ ls
> conversation  conversation.rb mailbox.rb  message.rb  notification.rb receipt.rb
> ```

Why isn't my app finding the model? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Message` is now namespaced as `Mailboxer::Message`. [According to the upgrade documentation](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer#upgrading), you also need to run through a few steps when upgrading from 0.11 to 0.12:

```
rails generate mailboxer:namespacing_compatibility
rails generate mailboxer:install -s
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I noticed and ran the migrations but they didn't solve the problem for me, but I didn't notice the namespace change. I had do move some views around and it started working again. Thanks for the point in the right direction.

Comment: @Jeff can you post your solution please I am having a similar issue with Notification

Comment: @JeffFinn I moved some of the views into a subfolder in the `app/views` folder. I dont remember exactly which move fixed the error, but if I go back in my repo history, I created a few new folders that day... `app/views/mailboxer/conversations` (I think this was the one), `app/views/message_mailer` and `app/views/notification_mailer`.